# Async.ParallelLimit callback already called

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js, asynchronous-javascript

I am using request module for downloading the reports.I am using parallelLimit method to limit number of simultaneous tasks.

Code to iterate array is:

```
_.each(strs,function(str){
    _.each(experiences,function(selectedExperience){  
        asyncTasks.push(function(callback){
            downloadReport(name,inp.btime,inp.etime,selectedExperience,callback);
            });

        });
    });
});
```

Code for async task function is:

```
 var downloadReport = function(Name,startTime,endTime,selectedExperience,callback){
    request.post({
                headers: myHeaders,
                uri: strurl,
                form: formObject,
                method: 'POST'
              }, function (err, res, body) {
              if(err){



        downloadReport(kpiName,startTime,endTime,selectedExperience,callback);            
                      }
                      else if(res)
                      {
                        if(body.indexOf("some string")>=0){
                              console.log("No records returned!!!");
                                callback(null,arr);                   
                          }
                          else if(!(body.indexOf("some string")>=0))
                          {     

                            var samp=body.substring(body.indexOf("\n")+1);

                            csv.fromString(samp, {headers: true})
                            .on("data",function(data){
                            arr.push(data);
                            })
                            .on("end",function(){ 
                                console.log("Array Length:",arr.length);
                                callback(null,arr);
                            });
                          }
                          else
                          {
                              //some code here
                                for (i=0;i<a.length;i=i+2){
                                    downloadReport(Name,a[i],a[i+1],selectedExperience,callback);//calling the same function
                                }
                          }
                      }
                  });

        }
```

code for async parallel limit is

```
async.parallelLimit(asyncTasks,3,function(err, results){
    if(err) console.log(err);
    doSomething();
});
```

Requirement is to invoke doSomething() only once after all async tasks are executed.But I am getting following error:

```
 if (fn === null) throw new Error("Callback was already called.");
               ^
```

How to call callback only once in this situation?

Comment: Aren't you passing any callback to that `downloadReport(Name,a[i],a[i+1],selectedExperience);//calling the same function` recursive invocation?

Comment: @Bergi In each downloadReport call I am passing different start time and end time.It is a recursive invocation.So how to handle this situation?

Comment: Well, something like `async.each(a, …)` instead of the loop probably?

Comment: @Bergi And I have to limit the number of requests going to the server

Comment: If your recursive algorithm dynamically creates new requests, you'll probably want to use a [queue](https://github.com/caolan/async#queue) for this.

Comment: @Bergi should I write return callback(.... ) somwhere in code?

Comment: When calling the callback, you usually don't need to `return` anything. And most of the time, you don't need to *call* any callbacks anyway, just pass the ones that `async` gives you around.

Comment: @Bergi I have updated my code.But still I am getting the same error.